# Is `height: auto;` needed when setting width on an image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When setting width on an `<img>`, either with `width` or `max-width`, I've seen that many developers and some frameworks (like bootstrap) also set `height: auto`.

Is `height: auto` required in such cases, and if so why? (Assuming you want to keep the image proportional when resized, and that `height` has not been set previously in CSS.)

Someone mentioned that it's needed for IE10 on Windows Phone 8. (Which seems odd to me.) Could it be that some browsers require this setting?

Example ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyy2f59e/show/)):

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 300px;
}
.maxwidth{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.width{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p><code>max-width: 100%</code>:</p>
<div><img class="maxwidth" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals"></div>

<p><code>width: 100%</code>:</p>
<div><img class="width" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals"></div>

<p>No <code>height: auto</code> is used, but images still stay proportional.</p>
```

Comment: this makes difference in IE 10 where first one image gets **height:34.14px ** and second one image gets **height:325.56px** i checked

Comment: IE 
version 10.0.9200.17377

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara, tested on IE 10.0.9200.17148 (update version: 10.0.22, on win 7), both images are proportional and have the same size. How are you getting your result? Which OS?

Comment: Why the down vote if I may ask?

Comment: i downvoted because i have checked and that even not worked with your given code in IE10 the only reason is that

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara, so you're saying that you cannot get the question to "work" and thus it's bad? If you see something that can be improved please say so. The question seems clear, and the code was just an example, which can be ignored. See the answers if you don't understand it. Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: thus how you can't close the case by accepting answer yes you can upvote the answer i agree with this but you should wait for other user that might gives confirmation with same IE version

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara the accepted answer can be changed at any time. If you are having some issue with the answer, comment on it stating why it doesn't work, and/or post your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, the [initial value for `height` *is* `auto`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/height), so unless it's been overridden somewhere else you shouldn't need to specify `height: auto`.

Furthermore I don't know how tightly this relates to the `img` element itself over CSS images (backgrounds, etc.), but I believe the browser should handle this automatically anyway. If this documentation does also apply to the `img` element, I believe the the *Default Sizing Algorithm* section of the [CSS Image Values and Replaced Content Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#default-sizing) explains how the browser should handle this:

> The default sizing algorithm is defined as follows:
>
> - If the specified size is a definite width and height, the concrete object size is given that width and height.
> - If the specified size is only a width or height (but not both) then the concrete object size is given that specified width or height. **The other dimension is calculated as follows:**
>
>   1. If the object has an intrinsic aspect ratio, the missing dimension of the concrete object size is calculated using the intrinsic aspect ratio and the present dimension.
>   2. Otherwise, if the missing dimension is present in the object's intrinsic dimensions, the missing dimension is taken from the object's intrinsic dimensions.
>   3. Otherwise, the missing dimension of the concrete object size is taken from the default object size.

---

#### Update

It appears Bootstrap uses it to override any custom `height` attribute present on an `img` element to ensure the `height` is always calculated from the `width`.

Comment: So you mean that they set `height: auto` to only override any other possible CSS `height` declarations? I would expect there to be more to it if even Bootstrap uses it like `height: auto; // Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching` (in `.img-responsive`).

Comment: @Qtax after a bit of Googling it appears that's used to handle when `img` elements themselves define a custom `height` attribute.

Comment: That was a suspect I had (the HTML height attribute), but wanted to see if people knew some other reasons or issues. This seems like a reasonable cause. Do you want to update the answer with this?

Comment: @Qtax added that to the bottom. :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Huh, I shouldn't have made that sandwich mid-answer

Answer (score 1):

The `height: auto` is only defined through the [`.img-responsive` class](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.0/docs/css/#overview-responsive-images). This is defined so that it overrides the images height attribute (if it is set).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2>Without auto height</h2>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="" width="200" height="100">

<h2>With auto height</h2>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="img-responsive" width="200" height="100">
```